# Inno Setup: Invalid Prototype

Tags: inno-setup

I am getting an "Invalid prototype for 'CheckForFile'". After hours and hours of trying to make setup download and install file (download part works, but I cannot find a way to run downloaded file), I am out of ideas. Why I am getting that error on this?

```
[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\AcroRdrDC1800920044_en_US.exe"; Description: "Install Adobe Reader"; Flags: shellexec skipifsilent; BeforeInstall: CheckForFile('{tmp}\AcroRdrDC1800920044_en_US.exe');

[Code]
function CheckForFile(Param: String): Boolean;
begin
  Result := FileExists(Param)
end;
```

Comment: If you want to check if file exists, you should use [function FileExists](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_fileexists)

Comment: @RobeN But I am using FileExists() already?

Comment: You should set Procedure for Check not the Function. 
You can just CheckForFile by a procedure described [Check if file exist in destination or else if doesn't abort the installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951327/inno-setup-check-if-file-exist-in-destination-or-else-if-doesnt-abort-the-ins) or you can just set a flag to skip if Files Does Not Exist: `Flag: skipifdoesntexist;` which is preferable solution if you don't need any custom event when File is Not Found.

Comment: @RobeN Great, thanks! I wasn't aware there is such a flag. Great solution! BTW I saw that question already, but I am getting an error like procedure cannot return value, use function and then I get error Invalid Prototype.

Comment: @BranislavMihaljev : you forgot `ExpandConstant(const S: String): String;` use it like `CheckForFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\AcroRdrDC1800920044_en_US.exe'));`

Comment: @moskito-x Yes, thanks, I found out that after I posted a question - to evaluate that tmp into the path, but that flag solved the issue and make function obsolete. Thanks to both!

Answer (score 1):

While there already is some truth within the comments, I'd like to share what I've learned so far anyway, just in case anyone needs it.

My observations are

- If I use the `Check` parameter with a `function` that returns a `boolean`, there is no *Invalid Prototype* error
- If I use the `BeforeInstall` or `AfterInstall` parameter with a `procedure` there is no error either
- Any other combination will cause the error

This led me to the following **conclusion**:

When using a procedure or function within the parameters of `[Files]` entry, *Inno Setup* creates a prototype for this function or procedure.

- A `procedure` prototype for `BeforeInstall` and `AfterInstall`, since these do not expect a return value
- A `function : boolean` protoype for `Check`, because this one expects a return value

After processing the `[Files]` section, the `[Code]` section is processed. Since a prototype for `CheckForFile` has already been declared as `procedure CheckFile(...);` the declaration `function CheckFile(...) : boolean` does not match the prototype and the error is shown.

Therefor changing the function to a procedure would work techically, but using `Check` would be the way to go in your case. In cases when we want to execute something before the installation, `BeforeInstall` is the way to go, but it does not allow returning values.